# How to disable Postfix logging?

Tags: server, 10.04, postfix, dovecot

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and I am trying to disable logging for both Postfix and Dovecot. Does anyone know how to do this? I have found references stating that there is a setting in /etc/syslog.conf but that file does not exist on my system.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I found it on my own. For all of those that have the same issue. Ubuntu 10.04 uses rsyslog and the default file is:

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

If you want to disable postfix logging just comment out the lines associated with "mail", the file is pretty self-explanatory.